# C# Winforms Dictionary DataGrid Binding Auto-Refresh Without Losing Focus

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, datagrid

#### Setup

- C# WinForms Application.

#### Summary

- Binding a dictionary to a datagridview.
- Updating the dictionary automatically updates the datagrid.
- The datagrid does not lose focus when the update happens.
- The binding works both ways (editing values in the grid updates the dictionary.

#### Scenario

- I have a class that calculates values
  based on data from a database.
- The data in this database constantly changes so hence, the calculated values change too.
- These calculated values are added to the properties of a custom object "MyCustomObject".
- Each "MyCustomObject" is then added to a dictionary (or the custom object is updated if it already exists).
- The Dictionary is bound to a datagrid.

#### The idea

- The idea is that the calculated vales continually change and thus update the dictionary which in turn updates the datagrid.
- Users who are interacting with the datagrid need to be able to see these changes automatically.
- It is imperative that the currently selected row in the datagrid does not lose focus when the grid is updated with the new custom object values.
- The binding must work both ways (editing values in the grid updates the dictionary too.

#### Question

- How can I implement this automatic binding so that I get the requirements that I need?
- I have already written the code to do all of the calculations and add/update the dictionary of MyCustomObjects.
- Examples of how to implement this datagrid binding would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The reason for it is I only use SO at work, and we have to use IE6, and IE6 under corporate lockdown doesn't support javascript and all of that glitter so clicking accept, in work, does nothing.

Comment: Good point, and point taken, just not so easy when you work 6am till 10pm and hate the site of a computer when you get home, but I'll make a point of doing it later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to accomplish this, your Dictionary would need to implement `IBindingList` and fire the `ListChanged` event whenever changes were made. Here's a sample (*very*) barebones implementation of `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` that also implements `IBindingList`:

```
public class BindableDictionary<TKey, TValue> : IDictionary<TKey, TValue>, IBindingList
{
    private Dictionary<TKey, TValue> source = new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>();

    void IBindingList.AddIndex(PropertyDescriptor property) { }
    object IBindingList.AddNew() { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    bool IBindingList.AllowEdit { get { return false; } }
    bool IBindingList.AllowNew { get { return false; } }
    bool IBindingList.AllowRemove { get { return false; } }
    void IBindingList.ApplySort(PropertyDescriptor property, ListSortDirection direction) { }
    int IBindingList.Find(PropertyDescriptor property, object key) { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    bool IBindingList.IsSorted { get { return false; } }
    void IBindingList.RemoveIndex(PropertyDescriptor property) { }
    void IBindingList.RemoveSort() { }
    ListSortDirection IBindingList.SortDirection { get { return ListSortDirection.Ascending; } }
    PropertyDescriptor IBindingList.SortProperty { get { return null; } }
    bool IBindingList.SupportsChangeNotification { get { return true; } }
    bool IBindingList.SupportsSearching { get { return false; } }
    bool IBindingList.SupportsSorting { get { return false; } }
    int System.Collections.IList.Add(object value) { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    void System.Collections.IList.Clear() { Clear(); }
    bool System.Collections.IList.Contains(object value) { if (value is TKey) { return source.ContainsKey((TKey)value); } else if (value is TValue) { return source.ContainsValue((TValue)value); } return false; }
    int System.Collections.IList.IndexOf(object value) { return -1; }
    void System.Collections.IList.Insert(int index, object value) { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    bool System.Collections.IList.IsFixedSize { get { return false; } }
    bool System.Collections.IList.IsReadOnly { get { return true; } }
    void System.Collections.IList.Remove(object value) { if (value is TKey) { Remove((TKey)value); } }
    void System.Collections.IList.RemoveAt(int index) { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    object System.Collections.IList.this[int index] { get { throw new NotImplementedException(); } set { throw new NotImplementedException(); } }

    private ListChangedEventHandler listChanged;

    event ListChangedEventHandler IBindingList.ListChanged
    {
        add { listChanged += value; }
        remove { listChanged -= value; }
    }

    protected virtual void OnListChanged(ListChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var evt = listChanged;

        if (evt != null) evt(this, e);
    }

    public void Add(TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        source.Add(key, value);

        OnListChanged(new ListChangedEventArgs(ListChangedType.Reset, -1));
    }

    public bool Remove(TKey key)
    {
        if (source.Remove(key))
        {
            OnListChanged(new ListChangedEventArgs(ListChangedType.Reset, -1));

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public TValue this[TKey key]
    {
        get
        {
            return source[key];
        }
        set
        {
            source[key] = value;

            OnListChanged(new ListChangedEventArgs(ListChangedType.Reset, -1));
        }
    }

    void ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>.Add(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item)
    {
        ((ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>)source).Add(item);

        OnListChanged(new ListChangedEventArgs(ListChangedType.Reset, -1));
    }

    bool ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>.Remove(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item)
    {
        if (((ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>)source).Remove(item))
        {
            OnListChanged(new ListChangedEventArgs(ListChangedType.Reset, -1));

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public bool ContainsKey(TKey key) { return source.ContainsKey(key); }
    public ICollection<TKey> Keys { get { return source.Keys; } }
    public bool TryGetValue(TKey key, out TValue value) { return source.TryGetValue(key, out value); }
    public ICollection<TValue> Values { get { return source.Values; } }
    public void Clear() { source.Clear(); }
    bool ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>.Contains(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item) { return ((ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>)source).Contains(item); }
    void ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>.CopyTo(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>[] array, int arrayIndex) { ((ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>)source).CopyTo(array, arrayIndex); }
    public int Count { get { return source.Count; } }
    bool ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>.IsReadOnly { get { return ((ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>)source).IsReadOnly; } }
    public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> GetEnumerator() { return source.GetEnumerator(); }
    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() { return GetEnumerator(); }
    bool ICollection.IsSynchronized { get { return false; } }
    object ICollection.SyncRoot { get { return null; } }
    void ICollection.CopyTo(Array array, int arrayIndex) { ((ICollection)source).CopyTo(array,arrayIndex); }
}
```

Unfortunately, the selected row may or may not change, depending on which grid you're using. Your best bet is to save off the key of the selected row whenever it changes, then reselect that row (if present) when the dictionary is updated. Otherwise, there's no way to guarantee that you'll maintain the selection.

Comment: Thanks.
Although I keep getting "BindingDictionary.BindableDictionary<TKey,TValue>' does not implement interface member 'System.Collections.ICollection.IsSynchronized'". and the same fo "SyncRoot" and "CopyTo(System.Array, int)". ANY IDEAS?

Comment: @Goober: I've added implementations for these methods, but it should be pretty self-explanatory.

Comment: I'm clearly missing something here. When I call "ADD", it fails and gives me the "Not Implemented Exception". But I don't understand why, because I can see an implementation?!?

Comment: @Goober: What is the *variable type* that you're calling `Add` on? I know that the value itself is a `BindableDictionary`, but what is the type you're using to actually call the function? (In other words, is the variable declared as `BindableDictionary` or `ICollection`, or something else?)

Comment: private BindableDictionary<string, MyCustomObject> customObjectDictionary = new BindableDictionary<string, MyCustomObject>(); - The error is thrown when I call add, but the error is thrown on the implementation of "this[int index]".

Comment: Actually I think it's failing when I call "gridControl1.DataSource = customObjectDictionary.Values;" - Is this not the correct way to bind the dictionary and the grid datasource?

Comment: Got it - stupid me - " gridControl1.DataSource = new BindingSource(customObjectDictionary.Values , null);"

Comment: How Would I implement this? "object System.Collections.IList.this[int index] { get { throw new NotImplementedException(); } set { throw new NotImplementedException(); } }" ?

Comment: The reason I ask is because I want to have an implementation where BindableDictionary has a value, and that value is a class that contains another BindableDictionary. The idea being to do something like this" myTopLevelDictionary["SomeKey"].SubDictionary;